# Mysql java cannot use connection method from another class

Tags: java, mysql, class

I am currently a fist year student doing software engineering and have currently ran into some problem while developing a project for university. I am currently working on a netbeans project which allows users to login and retrieve information from an mysql database. I currently have a separate class for datahandling where I have written the connection method see below.
However when I create the a new object of the datahandler in my Jframe class and try to call the connection method it does not allow me to use insert statements(see below) which I have programmed behind buttons(in order to retrieve information from txtfields). However when I move the connection method to the Jframe class it works perfectly fine. I was wonder if I am missing something really obvious here, or if it is just horrible design.

Thanks for your support!

```
    private void connection(){
    //from data handler class

    try{

    String mysqlUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";
    String username = "root";
    String password = "";
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(mysqlUrl, username, password);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("Got an exception");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());

    }
  }
 }

    private void btnRegisterActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

    try{
        Datahandler test = new Datahandler();
        test.connection();

        //create my mysql database connection


        String query = "INSERT INTO User(customerStatus ,title, firstname, lastname, contactNo, email, username, password)" 
                + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        pst = con.prepareStatement(query);

        pst.setString(1,"Beginner");
        pst.setString(2,cmdGender.getSelectedItem().toString());
        pst.setString(3,txtFirstname.getText());
        pst.setString(4,txtLastname.getText());
        pst.setString(5,txtPhone.getText());
        pst.setString(6,txtEmail.getText());
        pst.setString(7,txtUsername.getText());
        pst.setString(8,txtPassword.getText());
        pst.execute();

        /* inserts the values username and password into a separate table in the database and
        makes use of the to ensure that the login is sercure(I will possibly make a change to
            how the structure of the databases work since there is an security issue here
            */
            String query2 = "INSERT INTO Login(username, password)" 
                    + "VALUES (?, ?)";
            pst = con.prepareStatement(query2);
            pst.setString(1,txtUsername.getText());
            pst.setString(2,txtPassword.getText());

            pst.execute();


            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registration completed!");

            //reset registration boxes into empty text
            txtFirstname.setText("");
            txtLastname.setText("");
            txtPhone.setText("");
            txtEmail.setText("");
            txtUsername.setText("");
            txtPassword.setText("");

        }
        catch (Exception e){

            System.err.println("Got an exception");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Something went wrong try to register again");

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your `getConnection()` method is not returning anything. instead it is setting connection object to obejct con in that specific class.

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection(mysqlUrl, username, password);
```

This is why you are able to use it in your **Jframe**  class, because it contains **con** property which gets set in `getConnection()` method. but in your new class there is no filed **con** that is having proper connection object.

Modify method `getConnection()` so that it return connection object, and use that connection object returned from this method to further processing.